# reason behind "local variable 'variable ' referenced before assignmen" ERROR

Tags: python, django

I am not much familiar with django. Was working on a learning project. So here I am getting the error which says UnboundLocalError, "local variable 'url_array' referenced before assignment" . Here's my form.py , views.py and html code. Please have a look and give me a solution.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Images

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```
class Upload(View):

    def post(self, request):

        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            imageZip=request.FILES
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            url_array = []


            with ZipFile(imageZip['image'], 'r') as zip:
                zip.extractall()
                unzip_file= zip.namelist()
                for files in unzip_file:
                    with open(files, "rb") as file:
                        name = fs.save('read.jpg', file)
                    url_array.append(fs.url(name))
        else:
            form = ImageForm()


        return render(request, 'toDo_app.html', context = {'form': form, 'url':url_array})
```

toDo_app.html

```
<form  class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit" >Upload</button>


       </form>

          <br>

          {% if url %}
            <p>Uploaded file: </p>
            <ul>
              {% for urls in url %}
                <li>  <a href="{{ urls }}">{{ urls }}</a> </li>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>



          {% endif %}
```

So my error is at `return render(request, 'toDo_app.html', context = {'form': form, 'url':url_array})` line. 
Thanks for your time and I would be really grateful for an explanation and solution

Comment: you're using url_array without it ever being assigned anything. You only assign inside your conditional block, so if that conditional evaluates false, you're using an undefined symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `url_array` is initialised within the one body of the if statement. There is a chance that the `if` statement is never evaluated as `True` and hence the `url_array` will be uninitialised by the time your function returns. The function will not be able to return `render(...)` because `url_array` has no value.

Just make sure that the `url_array` is initialised with some default value outside the if statement, in the same scope with the return statement.

Comment: thank you so much for your help..Yeah I didn't really notice I had to make this as global variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

assign a url_array before if block

```
def post(self, request):
           url_array = []
           form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I wish I could tick two answers at a time. I have upvoted